Installing Mongo shell in Amazon Linux 2023 Cloud9 missing libsso and libcrypto
AWS Tutorial Attempt
I am going through this tutorial and in step 3 when trying to install the mongo shell with sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-shell I am getting the following error:
Last metadata expiration check: 0:14:54 ago on Mon Jun 10 13:06:44 2024.
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.0-1.amzn2.x86_64 from mongodb-org-5.0
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.0-1.amzn2.x86_64 from mongodb-org-5.0
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.0-1.amzn2.x86_64 from mongodb-org-5.0
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.0-1.amzn2.x86_64 from mongodb-org-5.0
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.0-1.amzn2.x86_64 from mongodb-org-5.0
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 from mongodb-org-5.0
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 from mongodb-org-5.0
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 from mongodb-org-5.0
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 from mongodb-org-5.0

... continues

I tried to install the packages sudo yum install openssl-devel but apparently is already installed:
Last metadata expiration check: 0:17:57 ago on Mon Jun 10 13:06:44 2024.
Package openssl-devel-1:3.0.8-1.amzn2023.0.11.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

Community Attempt
I found this dev community post saying Amazon Linux 2023 is not yet supported.
The response suggests this article with instructions to install MongoDB Community Edition.
Contents of /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-7.0.repo:
[mongodb-org-7.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2023/mongodb-org/7.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc

Successfully installed sudo yum install -y mongodb-org.
When connecting with mongosh I get the error:
mongosh: OpenSSL configuration error:
40A85444EE7F0000:error:030000A9:digital envelope routines:alg_module_init:unknown option:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/evp/evp_cnf.c:61:name=rh-allow-sha1-signatures, value=yes

Cloud9 instance:

Platform: Amazon Linux 2023

Question
How can I properly install the mongo client on Amazon Linux 2023 to configure DocumentDB?
Any help is very appreciated.
Thanks,

Now, after running the Community Attempt I don't get the same error (nothing provides...). But I get No match for argument: mongodb-org-shell Error: Unable to find a match: mongodb-org-shell

Legacy mongo shell is deprecated and not supported anymore. I am surprised that you got it installed with MongoDB version 7.0

Well, this is probably why I get bash: mongo: command not found above. But even after going through configuration I get an error when running mongosh => mongosh: OpenSSL configuration error: 40484740197F0000:error:030000A9:digital envelope routines:alg_module_init:unknown option:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/evp/evp_cnf.c:61:name=rh-allow-sha1-signatures, value=yes

I had the same error, but I handled it like this:
[root@mongo log]# mongosh "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
mongosh: OpenSSL configuration error:
0028A47DA57F0000:error:030000A9:digital envelope routines:alg_module_init:unknown option:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/evp/evp_cnf.c:61:name=rh-allow-sha1-signatures, value=yes

[root@mongo log]# vim /usr/share/crypto-policies/back-ends/DEFAULT/opensslcnf.config
#rh-allow-sha1-signatures = yes

[root@mongo log]# mongosh "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
Current Mongosh Log ID: 73a14d0gd077c8c672089650
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.1.3
Using MongoDB:          7.0.5
Using Mongosh:          2.1.3
mongosh 2.3.1 is available for download: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

test>


is this safe? any known issue doing this?
